# Webdata Scraping Html Span Variable Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, variables, web-scraping

Iam already able to successfully login:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3-10-6
import mechanize from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.request as urllib2 
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
#import cookielib ## http.cookiejar in python3

cj = cookielib.CookieJar() 
br = mechanize.Browser() 
br.set_cookiejar(cj) 
br.open("https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/Start.aspx?logout=true")

br.select_form(nr=0) 
br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtUserName'] = 'paulXXXX@googlemail.com' 
br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtPassword'] = 'XXXXXXXX' 
br.submit()

url = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/Start.aspx?logout=false'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
desired_data = soup.select("span", {"class":'.mainValueUnit'})
for x in desired_data:
    print('TEXT VALUE:', x.get_text(strip=True), '|', 'DATA_PEAK:', x.get('data-peak'))
```

Now I would like to scrap an the span tag (photovoltaic power)

```
<div class="widgetBox" data-name="pvPower">
    <div class="widgetHead">Aktuelle PV-Leistung</div>
    <div class="widgetSubHead"></div>
    <div class="widgetBody">
        <div class="mainValue">
            <img class="powerGaugeBackground" src="/Images/Dashboard/gauge.png" alt="" />
            <img class="powerGaugePointer" src="/Images/Dashboard/currentPlantPowerPointer.png" alt="" />
            <span
                class="mainValueAmount" 
                data-peak="4920"
                data-value="300"
                data-timestamp="2022-10-02T09:15:00">-</span>
            <span class="mainValueUnit"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widgetFooter">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UserControlShowDashboard1_currentplantPowerWidget_FooterLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UserControlShowDashboard1$currentplantPowerWidget$FooterLink&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Energie und Leistung »</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to scrap and print the span value? Its a dynamic variable for photovoltaic_power, examined:

```
<span class="mainValueAmount" data-peak="4920" data-value="908" data-timestamp="2022-10-02T13:00:00">1177</span>
```

"1177" number is the dynamic number iam looking for. Thank you

Comment: THERE'S NO NEED TO SHOUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is correct, and it's not loaded/enriched dynamically with Javascript, this is how you can get that data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="widgetBox" data-name="pvPower">
    <div class="widgetHead">Aktuelle PV-Leistung</div>
    <div class="widgetSubHead"></div>
    <div class="widgetBody">
        <div class="mainValue">
            <img class="powerGaugeBackground" src="/Images/Dashboard/gauge.png" alt="" />
            <img class="powerGaugePointer" src="/Images/Dashboard/currentPlantPowerPointer.png" alt="" />
            <span
                class="mainValueAmount" 
                data-peak="4920"
                data-value="300"
                data-timestamp="2022-10-02T09:15:00">-</span>
            <span class="mainValueUnit"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widgetFooter">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UserControlShowDashboard1_currentplantPowerWidget_FooterLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UserControlShowDashboard1$currentplantPowerWidget$FooterLink&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Energie und Leistung »</a>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

desired_data = soup.select('.mainValueAmount')
for x in desired_data:
    print('TEXT VALUE:', x.get_text(strip=True), '|', 'DATA_PEAK:', x.get('data-peak'))
```

Result in terminal:

```
TEXT VALUE: - | DATA_PEAK: 4920
```

For BeautifulSoup documentation, visit https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thank you for reply! I found out, that I need to grep the span tag, since the tag is representing my current pvPower.

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
                                                                                                                                           
 x = soup.find("span", {"class":"widgetBox", "data-name": "pvPower"})['data-name']`

Comment: .. so, in conclusion, the HTML you posted in your original question was wrong. @StraightFoward

Comment: but something is still wrong..

Comment: I edited my question. sorry for confusion. but now it should be clear. thanks for engagement

Comment: It was clear from the beginning. You subsequent comment was confusing, implying the page structure was different. My answer is correct, providing that page looks like you say it looks. @StraightFoward

Comment: Barry thank you. I need the "span" value/tag. The webside updates the solar value every second...

Comment: <span class="mainValueUnit"></span>

Comment: Then just replace the class value in my code above: `desired_data = soup.select('.mainValueUnit')`. Did you inspect the network calls, what is the source of the value being constantly refreshed?

Comment: and how to print mainValueUnit? I would like to share my current code...

Comment: Barry if look at the last snippet I posted in my question, the value on the right end is needed. How could I inspect network calls?

Comment: Barry I updated my question with current code..

Comment: I don't see any changes. My code will correctly print the text value for element with class `mainValueAmount` @StraightFoward. Of course, if that element is not part of the static HTML of the page, requests/bs4 cannot access it. You may want to investigate the source of that information being pulled into page, and scrape that source. I cannot help more, given I don't have access to that page.

Comment: ah okay yes thats the case, because its not static. any instructions on how to check? or could i mail you?

Comment: Check in Dev tools - Network Tab, under either XHR section, either WS section (web-sockets).